# How can I fix this warning "Illegal string offset" in PHP & PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I want to fix this error. I want to get the column that name in database is role and put it into session

```
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $statment = $con->prepare("select * from users where username = ? and password = ? limit 1");
    $statment->execute(array($username,$password));
    $count = $statment->rowCount();
    $row = $statment->fetchColumn();

    if($count > 0)
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        $_SESSION['role'] = $row['role'];

        echo 'User Name : '.$_SESSION['username'].' , Password : '.$_SESSION['password'].' , Role : '.$_SESSION['role'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Failed To Login';
    }
```

Comment: You maybe want to post your full error message and on which line you got it.

Comment: @Antono: don't need it. you can pass the bind values as an array to the execute call.

Comment: Besides, @Antono - that's a `mysqli_` function, it's incompatible with PDO (see the tags + the functions used on the statement).

Comment: @Qirel Aah, I see now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

This function returns a **VALUE**, not an array:

```
$row = $statment->fetchColumn();
  ^---your column, a string

$_SESSION['role'] = $row['role'];
                       ^^^^^^^^^^---treating your string as an array, with invalid index
```

Comment: The function he should be using is `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`.